# Is it possible to apply changes to all objects in Array without using "for each" or "for" in Swift 3?

Tags: arrays, swift

for example

```
var imageViewArray:UIImageView = [imageView1,imageView2,imageView3]
```

I want to chage same`imageView.image = img` or `imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` to all Image View inside the array

Comment: And what's wrong with a `for in` loop or `forEach(_:)`? Also annotating `imageViewArray` as a `UIImageView` is nonsensical.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that. I just want to know is there any option in Swift 3, thats it. And I know its specifying is nonsensical but consider like this `var imageViewArray = [UIImageView]()`

Comment: But both `for in` loops and `forEach(_:)` are specifically designed to iterate through an array, allowing the caller to do something with the elements. Of course there are always other ways of doing this – you *could* subscript the array 3 times and manually mutate each element, you *could* create an extension to specifically assign to the `image` property of the elements. But these are pretty bad solutions. It's really unclear exactly what you're actually looking for here.

Comment: Shortly: No, it's not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1. It's an array

First of all it's not

```
var imageViewArray:UIImageView
```

but

```
var imageViewArray:[UIImageView]
```

because you want an array of `UIImageView` right?

### 2. Naming conventions

Secondly is Swift we don't name a variable after it's type so `imageViewArray` becomes `imageViews`.

### 3. map

Now if you really hate the for in and the foreach your can write

```
imageViews = imageViews.map { imageView in
    imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return imageView
}
```

or as suggested by *Bohdan Ivanov* in the comments

```
imageViews.map { $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }
```

### 4. Wrap up

This answer shows you how to use the **wrong** construct (map) to do something that should be made with the **right** construct (for in).

That's the point of having several constructs, everything could be made with an `IF THEN` and a `GOTO`. But a good code uses the construct that best fits that specific scenario.

So, the best solution for this scenario is absolutely the `for in` or the `for each`

```
imageViews.forEach { $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }
```

Comment: Just to clarify: you can write `imageViews.map { $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }` as well so there will be one-liner

Comment: @BohdanIvanov: Correct. Since `UIImageView` is a class it will work. It won't work on structs instead. I'll update my code, thanks.

Comment: @BohdanIvanov But then that's creating an array that the caller never uses – and the compiler will rightly warn about it (although assigning the result back to `imageViews` was just as pointless). The equivalent without the resultant array is  `imageViews.forEach { $0.isUserInteractionEnabled = true }`, so we're back where we started. Using `map` over `forEach` in this case *solely* for the sake of avoiding `forEach` (for some reason) is a pretty bad idea.

Comment: @Hamish, I totally agree, just don't want to discourage anyone from using sugar syntax.